# StackOverflowException on Singleton

Tags: c#, oracle, singleton

My Singleton is throwing a `StackOverflowException`, but yesterday it worked fine and the unique change was the database in the Connection String. It is a console application and the debug is very complicated:

```
class OracleSingleton
{
    private static OracleConnection instance;

    private OracleSingleton() { }

    public static OracleConnection Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    instance = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConnection"].ConnectionString);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogHelper.WriteMessage("Error trying to create a new connection. - " + ex.Message.ToString() + " - " + ex.InnerException.ToString().Trim());
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

My App.config:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleConnection" connectionString="Password=somepassword;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=someuser;Data Source=DATABASE01"/>
  </connectionStrings>
    //Some stuff
</configuration>
```

Can you guys show me what is wrong and why yesterday it worked fine?

**EDIT:**

I use the Singleton to do a lot of things. I Know that the problem is in the singleton because my application shows the `StackoverflowException` without log anything, who is one of the places where I use the Singleton. Below, my `LogHelper.WriteMessage` method, who is called at the first line of program to say" Hi, the application is running right now ":

```
public static void WriteMessage(string info)
{
    using (OracleConnection conn = OracleSingleton.Instance)
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO TB_LOG (DT_LOG, ID_PERMISSAO, ID_USUARIO, NM_USUARIO, DS_LOG) VALUES (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 5025, 5025, 'IMPORTADORCAIXA', '" + info + "')", conn))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - Erro ao conectar com o banco. por favor, verifique o erro: " + ex.Message.ToString() + ", " + cmd.CommandText.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    new LogHelper();
    eventLog.WriteEntry(info);
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - " + info);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show where you access `Instance`? Does the `LogHelper` log something? My guess is that the connection fails today and therefor something different happens. The code you posted so far does not seem to be able to create a StackOverflowException, so please show where you call it.

Comment: As a note, since you never create an instance of OracleSingleton, you could just declare the class static. No need for a private constructor.

Comment: Singleton looks fine, i think it's something with your constructor

Comment: Debugging may be complicated, but it seems necessary in this case.  *At least* identifying where/when the exception occurs.  Getting the stack would be immensely useful as well, though may involve using a tool like WinDbg.

Comment: Thank you guys for reply. I has edited the post with more information.

Comment: @Csorgo: Why do you call `new LogHelper();` in `WriteMessage` and then not do anything with the new object?  Also, having a single static Connection object seems like a *famously* bad idea.  What happens after that object is disposed?  As for the stack overflow exception, you'll still at least need to identify where it's happening.  We can't meaningfully guess by looking at the code you're showing us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "singleton" is indeed recursive on some paths. What happens if this line

```
instance = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConnection"].ConnectionString);
```

throws exception, for example if connection string is invalid? You log that exception with `WriteLog` which again references singleton with

```
using (OracleConnection conn = OracleSingleton.Instance)
```

So if connection string is invalid, or connection creation constantly fails for other reason - you go into recursion and eventually end with `StackOverflowException` when stack space is exhausted.

By the way, with

```
using (OracleConnection conn = OracleSingleton.Instance)
```

you also dispose your connection, making it unusable for subsequent invocations.

Best way to resolve it is to just get rid of singleton, there is no need for it. It's bad practice to have global connection - just create it every time you need it and dispose (close) when you are done with it. Connection pool will manage the rest for you.

If you don't want to do serious refactoring for some reason, at least change to something like this:

```
public static OracleConnection Create() {
    // no need to catch any exceptions here
    return new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConnection"].ConnectionString);
}
```

And use as you already do:

```
using (OracleConnection conn = OracleSingleton.Create())
```

Comment: you're right. Now i see the problem. I've been study a lot, but my programming journey is just beginning. Thank you to all for all the hints. It certain will help a lot in my code quality.